# windows 10 javascript problem

Tags: windows, javascript

i cant enable javascripts at windows 10 any prblem ?
just updated my OS up to win 10 and cant enable java in TOR browser

Comment: Are you talking about Java or Javascript? Please describe your problem a bit more in detail.

Comment: What errors do you get and on which pages? How do you know it's not loaded? Is it loaded on this page? Which version of Tor Browser do you use?